# How To play a video stream from exoplayer?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

Hello i have problem i want to play video stream from url link but i have some issue after i use complete url link or without blank space exoplayer player library can detected but after i use file url link blank space cannot detected

example
http://www.something.com/folder/hmmm.mp4 //worked success
after i use this
http://www.something.com/folder/hmmm iknow this blank space.mp4// cannot worked

can someone helpme please thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna answer using the code I used to play video at a URL in exoplayer--

```
String videoURL="https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/April/58ffdcc8_5-mix-wet-and-cry-batter-together-brownies/5-mix-wet-and-cry-batter-together-brownies.mp4" ; 


MediaSource mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab"))
        .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoURL));
```

So you'll have to give the entire address of video along with video type extension to run successfully.